# What software is available for drawing plans?

Tags: software-recommendation

I want to draw a plan with measurements, trees, entries, North sign, paths, something similar to AutoCad but for lands.

What would you recommend?

Comment: I use QCAD to draw planning applications (so mostly buildings). It's not exactly free (I haven't tried the trial version - my employer paid for it) but it's the best of all the CAD programs I've tried, and the manual is very clear and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There's some alternatives like FreeCad, It seems to be a good software I used before a twice of times but for time I can't explore fully.

```
sudo apt-get install freecad
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend LibreOffice Draw which is freely downloadable from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

There are a number of templates available and the software in quite intuitive to use with significant online help available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-free program [Draftsight](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/) available from Dassault Systemes. 
It opens even huge 20MB layouts created in Autocad.